# How to add a simple text label in a jqGrid form?

Tags: forms, jqgrid

When using the Add or Edit form from the pager I'm wondering how a simple static label can be added in the form without it creating any additional columns in it's affect on colNames[]'s and colModel[]'s. For example I have a quite simple typical Add form which opens from the pager containing a few label's and form elements: Name, Email, Web Site, etc., and then the lower section of the form has a few drop down menus containing the number 1 through 10 with the idea being to ask the user to pick a value between 1 and 10 to put a value on the importance to them about the product or service which is listed beside it. Just above this section I want to add some text only to give a brief instruction asking the user to "Choose the importance of the following products and services using the scale: [1=Low interest --- 10=Very high interest]". I cannot figure out how to get a text label inserted in the form without having to define a column with a formoption{} etc which is not needed for just some descriptive text. I know about the "bottominfo: 'some text'" for adding text to the bottom of the form but I need to insert some text similar to that mid-way (or other positions) in the form without it affecting the tabular structure of the grid. Is this even possible? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify Edit or Add forms inside of [afterShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events). The ids of the form fields are like "tr_Name". There consist from "tr_" prefix and the corresponding column name.

I modified the code example from my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405029/jqgrid-disable-form-fields-when-editing/3405961#3405961) so that in the Add dialod there exist an additional line with the bold text "Additional Information:". In the "Edit" dialog (like one want in the original question) the input field for one column is disabled. You can see the example live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFormEdit.htm). I hope that a working code example can say more as a lot of words.