# jqGrid. add dialog

Tags: jqgrid

I have jqGrid with some columns, I want to add additional fields in Add dialog, that not displaying in grid, but sending in request. How i can make this functional?

Comment: I wanted to answer to your other question and reread this question one more time. At the first time my answer was on the wrong question. I updated my answer. Please if you want to receive answer in the future comment answers in any way. Without any response from your side I see no sense in answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify Add dialog inside of [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) event handler. You can see a working example [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFormEdit.htm). This example I made as an answer to the question ["jqGrid: Disable form fields when editing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405029/jqgrid-disable-form-fields-when-editing/3405961#3405961) (see also a close question ["How to add a simple text label in a jqGrid form?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836251/how-to-add-a-simple-text-label-in-a-jqgrid-form/3838407#3838407))

**UPDATED**: I reread your question and could see that I answered originally on another question as you asked. What you need is just usage of [editData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) parameter which can be for example like

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{del:false,search:false,refresh:false},
            {}, // edit parameters
            { // add parameters
                url: '/myAddUrl',
                editData: {
                    someStaticParameter: "Bla Bla",
                    myDynamicParameter: function() {
                        return (new Date()).toString();
                    }
                }
            }
            );
```

see [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomAddData.htm). The demo has nothing on the server side, but you can easy verify with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), that the data sent to the the server contain `someStaticParameter` and `myDynamicParameter` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This one is good. I'm voting this one up.

This solution applies to what I'm looking for. I have a users table with the typical username, password, and etc details. I have an edit and add button as well.

Security-wise, it's not good to send all the users along with their passwords. So in the edit form, an admin can only edit everything except the password.

In the add form, an admin can create a new account with a new password. Since the password field doesn't exist in the grid, it will not show in the add form. By following this example, I'm able to add a custom field without exposing my users passwords. Thanks a lot Oleg