# jQGrid, how to make a column editable in the add dialog but not during (inline) edits

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, editing

I have a jQGrid with a column that I only want to be editable when adding a new row.

I've seen examples of how to do this when edits and adds are both happening in a dialog but is there a way to do this with in-line editing?

I've tried using grid.setColProp() in beforeShowForm:, but this doesn't work ( the column remains read only and is not present in the add dialog).

Example of dialog based column enable/disable:
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFormEdit.htm

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because you use the example from my old answers ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405029/jqgrid-disable-form-fields-when-editing/3405961#3405961) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836251/how-to-add-a-simple-text-label-in-a-jqgrid-form/3838407#3838407)) I feel that I should answer also on your question.

In the [old example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFormEdit.htm) all fields, which can be modified during Add or Edit dialogs, has property  `editable:true`. The fields which should be shown only in the Add dialog will be made hidden inside of [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) event handle. In the same way we can **temporary** switch some fields to `editable:false` before call of the editRow method and reset back to the `editable:true` immediately after the call:

```
onSelectRow: function(id) {
    if (id && id !== lastSel) {
        grid.jqGrid('restoreRow',lastSel);
        var cm = grid.jqGrid('getColProp','Name');
        cm.editable = false;
        grid.jqGrid('editRow', id, true, null, null, 'clientArray');
        cm.editable = true;
        lastSel = id;
    }
}
```

You can see this live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFormAndInlineEdit.htm).

**UPDATE:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) allows to define `editable` as callback function. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function). It allows to make the column editable in some rows and holding non-editable for other rows.

Comment: Great! Have you any blog posts, publications or another stack answers on jQGrid?

Comment: @DotNET Ninja: Currently I write only answers on stackoverflow and in the trirand forum. I hope I will find time next time and write a blog or articles or a book which describes how to work effectively with jqGrid.

Comment: @Oleg: This seems to work if we want to make one column as not editable across all rows. Is there a way to make a particular column editable for some rows and not for other rows? I looked around and was not able to find anything close to what I am looking for. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @RRK: The *current value* of property `editable` will be used by `editRow`. So if you change *common* property `editable` before every call of `editRow` like I shown then you do can make non-editable selected rows only.

Comment: @Oleg: Thank you. It is working now. I missed the part where you reset the editable property after editRow call.