# Column editable show different in Add/Edit Model Popup. How?

Tags: jqgrid

Structure of my grid columns.

Now problem is that **I want CompanyName only editable and sown in Edit ModelPopup**

and

for **adding ModelPopup I want all the below to be shown in popup.**

How do I do that?

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'companyID', index: 'companyID', width: 60, editable: false,
      editoptions: { readonly: true } },
    { name: 'companyName', index: 'companyName', width: 190, editable: true,
      editrules: { required: true} },
    { name: 'companyCity', index: 'companyCity', width: 190, editable: true,
      editrules: { required: true} },
    { name: 'companyState', index: 'companyState', width: 50, sortable: false,
      align: 'center', editable: true, editrules: { required: true} },
    { name: 'action', index: 'action', width: 80, sortable: false, align: 'center',
      editable: false, }
 ]
...
 .navGrid('#pager10', { view:true, edit: true, add: true, del: true }
```

Comment: Why you don't use up-voting (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)? You asked 42 questions, receive many answers and you have 0 votes. Do you receive no answer which was helpful for you in any ways? Starting with 15 points of reputation you can just clicking the upward pointing arrow (with the tooltip "This answer is useful") to the left of the answer. In some situation the accepted answers will not calculated at all only voting up are important. So if you want be polite to people who give  answers on your question you should vote the answer up.

Comment: You can also vote up any other question or answer which you found helpful or interesting. It helps other people to find the best answer or the most interesting question.

Comment: I am sorry Oleg. Didn't pay attention to that. I will certainly keep that in mind from now on and will revisit all my questions. I get alot of help from StackOver flow and I respect that. Thanks

Comment: You welcome! It is a standard problem for many people who start with the stackoverflow. The people just don't know the rules and small tricks and so not follow there. For example, in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work are explained that you can use "@Oleg" in the comment to make notifination about your replay. One more link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-do-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user-work-the-official-faq could gives you many additional interesting information how to use stackoverflow.com. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple way to do this is to use [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) method. See my old answer on the same subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405029/jqgrid-disable-form-fields-when-editing/3405961#3405961).

In case of [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing) instead of [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) you can follow another suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307147/jqgrid-how-to-make-a-column-editable-in-the-add-dialog-but-not-during-inline-e/4308172#4308172).