# Is it possible to have additional fields in jqgrid form?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is possible to have additional fields in jqgrid form? Say perhaps additional datepicker or select list or even an additional input field etc that is not shown on the gird itself.

Can anyone assist me in understanding how I can implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can include additional fields in the Add/Edit forms in different way.

The simplest way is to add hidden columns in the grid. For example the properties for the additional column could solve the problem:

```
hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, hidedlg: true
```

Another approach is to modify Add/Edit dialog manually (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5512509/315935)) and the Add form of [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFormAndInlineEdit.htm).