# how to show readonly fields in edit form in jqgrid or other way to show whole text from readonly column

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

jqGrid colModel contains read-only multi line column defined using properties below.
Content line lenghts are greater than column width, text is to long so that tooltio does not show its whole content. It is not possible to see whole content.

I'm looking for a way allow user to see whole column content.
For example, if edit form button is pressed, this column content should de displayeid in edit form as readonly textarea.
However, readonly columns does not appear in edit form.

How to allow user to see whole column content ?

```
colModel: [{
"name":"LoggedLongText",
"editable":false,"width":539,
"classes":"jqgrid-readonlycolumn","fixed":true,
"hidden":false,"searchoptions":{"sopt":["cn","eq","ne","lt","le","gt","ge","bw","ew","nc"]}}
}]
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Is the setting

```js
editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: "readonly" }
```

probably what you need?

**UPDATED:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) supports more values for `editable` property starting with version 4.8. [The wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function) described that `editable` can be function and it supports additionally three string values in case of using form editing: `"hidden"`, `"disabled"` and `"readonly"`.

Comment: I want to readonly username field only in edit mode. How can i do it? b/c when i apply this changes in username then in add mode readonly is enable due to which i cannot able to add new username. Plz suggest.

Comment: @farhan: If you use [the inline editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing) look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307147/jqgrid-how-to-make-a-column-editable-in-the-add-dialog-but-not-during-inline-e/4308172#4308172). If you use [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) read [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405029/jqgrid-disable-form-fields-when-editing/3405961#3405961). Both answers shows how you can **dynamically** change `editable` or any other properties of the column for the row.

Comment: Thankx, it fixed. I've another issue. Please see the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346722/how-to-display-error-message-in-add-edit-dialogue-of-jqgrid-while-checking-duplic    , i shall be thankful to you for looking this issue as i'm stuck.

Comment: @CJRamki: You are welcome! In some cases `editoptions: { disabled: "disabled" }` is even better. One can set **any** attribute on the editable filed (`<input>` in the most case). Just if the name of the property of `editoptions` is unknown it will be interpreted by jqGrid as the name of additional attribute which need be set.

Comment: Hmmm... like `required:true` option? @Oleg

Comment: @Oleg: Was confused why i'm getting the text cursor on hovering the read only field? Thinking that was editable tried many changes.

Answer (score 3):

To show readonly fields you might try using the `"disabled:disabled"` inside `editoptions`.

Yet another option is to use a custom element type that returns a span as below:

```
colModel: [ 
      ... 
      {name:'price', ..., editable:true, edittype:'custom', editoptions:{custom_element: myelem, custom_value:myvalue} },
      ...
   ]
..
function myelem (value, options) {
  var el = document.createElement("span");
  $(el).val(value);    // be sure to escape special characters as necessary.
  return el;
}

function myvalue(elem, operation, value) {
// just reutrun null or empty string.
return "";
}
```

I prefer this over using "`readonly:readonly`", because the `readonly` option wraps an input control around the cell value, the input control still receives focus, which I think is misleading to the user. Using `"disabled:disabled"` keeps the input element from receiving better, which is slightly better, in terms of usability.

Using a span is much better. Interestingly, jqGrid sends even "[unsuccessful](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)" form controls to the server.

Hope this helps.
-- jqr

Answer (score 1):

To show readonly fields on EditForm, you must try using the `{readonly: true}` property inside editoptions for a jqGrid column and will work.

Comment: Yeah. That would be a copy, really, if not verbatim.