# Jqgrid getting value that we entered and change the editable attribute of a form

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

excuse me guys, but i'm having these two problems. i hope you guys can help me with this.

here is part of my code

```
jQuery("#VWWMODULE").jqGrid(
{
url:'loadstatic.php?q=2&t=CORE_VW_WMODULE',
datatype: "json", 
mtype: "POST", 
colNames:['Id', 'From Range', 'To Range'],
colModel:
[
    {
        name:'id',
        index:'id',
        width:7,
        editable:true,
        edittype:'text',
        editrules:{required:true},
        editoptions:{maxlength:7, size:7},
        formoptions:{rowpos:1, elmprefix:'  '},
        key:true
    },
    {
        name:'rangefrom',
        index:'rangefrom',
        width:7,
        editable:true,
        edittype:'text',
        editrules:{required:true, number:true},
        editoptions:{maxlength:7, size:7},
        formoptions:{rowpos:6, elmprefix:'  '}
    },
    {
        name:'rangeto',
        index:'rangeto',
        width:7,
        editable:true,
        edittype:'text',
        editrules:{required:true, number:true, custom:true, custom_func:frtid},
        editoptions:{maxlength:7, size:7},
        formoptions:{rowpos:7,elmprefix:'  '}
    }
]
```

1. as you can see in the 'rangeto' i'm having a custom validation. this validation is simple actually. it just needs to check whether the value of 'rangeto' that we input is greater than the value of 'rangefrom'. now how can i get the value from 'rangefrom' so i can compare it with value from 'rangeto' in the custom validation function?
2. for my second question is about index 'id'. it used as a primary key for a table. so it shouldn't be changed when in editing mode. i'm saying when in add mode, a user can input it anyway he want. but once he submit it, the value can't be changed. in edit mode, the user can still see the 'id' value but he can't change it because it is ineditable. how can this be done?

EDIT

okay, now i'm having another problem. this is a simple question though.

1. how to make the custom validation function called just when in add mode? cause my function will gives error message when in edit mode when it should not be called

can any of you guys please help me with these 3 problems that i had?

EDIT

solved with some more explanation from [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/getting-value-that-we-entered-and-change-the-editable-attribute-of-a-form/#p28796)

Comment: The goal of stackoverflow is not providing help forum where somebody solve all your problems. The goal is *sharing common questions and the answers (solutions of common problems)*. Because of that commutative questions are evil. Such questions can be bad indexed and so other will be not able to find the solution. You should separate different problems in different questions.

Comment: I recommend you to use `beforeCheckValues` callback, set `id` field to readonly or hide inside of `beforeShowForm` (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3405961/315935) and [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3952654/315935)).

Comment: i'm sorry about this thing. i just want to make it more simple so i don't have to create a new questions and thus doesn't really waste some space in the server. i also had some research in the documentation before i ask things and had been searched for some similar problems but either couldn't get the right question (as you said bad indexed), couldn't get the answer, or the question that i found is similar yet not really the same such in this case, i've found answer about infield editing but it couldn't really solve my problem. anyway thanks for the response and the answer, i'll check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, that your main problem now is only changing of `id` in the grid after editing.

First of all it's extremely important that you write in all your questions: which editing mode you use and whether you use `loadonce: true` if you load data from the server (`datatype: "json"`).

Only indirectly one can suppose that you use form editing mode because you use `formoptions` options in `colModel`. Form editing has `reloadAfterSubmit` option (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties)) which default value is `true`. It means that jqGrid reload the whole content of the grid after successful submitting of editing of one row. The setting simplify interface to the server. If you use the default option then you will have no problem with id editing and no problem with correct sorting of data after editing.

If you do decide to use `reloadAfterSubmit` option then you have to do additional work. The server should response with new value of `id`. The `id` will be typically **generated** by database in case of holding data in the database. You have to implement [afterSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) callback which should decode new `id` from the server response and return it.

If you do use inline editing and need to change `id` then I would forward you to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16002113/315935). `aftersavefunc` callback from the example contains the code which modify `id`.

**UPDATED**: I'v seen [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/getting-value-that-we-entered-and-change-the-editable-attribute-of-a-form/#p28750) that you asked the same question in the trirand forum. I wanted shortly comment one point from the Tony's answer.

Every Add or Edit form contains table with the data (another table contains buttons which one see at the bottom of the form). The first two and the last one rows of the table are mostly hidden and contains (or can contains) helpful information:

[image]

For example the last row contains input field with `id="id_g"`. The row exist event you don't have the column `id` (like in your grid). So `$("#id_g").val()` contains the rowid of the editing row. Add dialog contains the string `"_empty"` on the place.

**UPDATED 2**: If you need to display `id` field in Add and Edit form but make it readonly you need just use `readonly: 'readonly'` property for `id` column (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7058114/315935)). The next problem: you should use `recreateForm: true` property for *both* Add and Edit forms.

I don't recommend you to use `reloadAfterSubmit: true`, but if you really need to use the option you should returns from the server (from *savewmodule.php*) the id of new added row and you have to use `afterSubmit` callback to get the new id from the server response and return it in documented way (`return [true, "", new_id];`). Additionally you have to set content of "id" column of grid after saving of row. You should modify `id` property of `postdata` parameter of `afterSubmit` callback.