# JQGrid asp.net mvc3. Custom inline edit. (Commercial license)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

In the Edit Row Inline Example on the Trirand demo site:
http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/grid/editrowinlinecustomedittype

How can I make e.g. 'OrderDate' and 'ShipName' editable, but ONLY IF e.g. 'CustomedID' is 'CHOPS'? Cells should not be editable in rows where 'CustomerID' is anything else.

I am running v 4.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

[Inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing) supports the following feature which you can use: if a row (`<tr>` element) has "not-editable-row" class the editing of the row will not permitted.

So you can include in your jqGrid the custom `loadComplete` event handler which tests the contain of `'CustomedID'` column for all rows and add `"not-editable-row"` class on the rows where the contain is not equal to `'CHOPS'`. The example from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575192/jqgrid-change-background-color-of-row-based-on-row-cell-value-by-column-name/6575634#6575634) could help you. You should just rename `myAltRowClass` to `not-editable-row` and change the criteria used in the testing from `$(row.cells[iCol]).children("input:checked").length>0` to `$(row.cells[iCol]).text() !== 'CHOPS'`.

Comment: I only want some cells in the row editable, not the entire row.

Comment: @user323313: Look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307147/jqgrid-how-to-make-a-column-editable-in-the-add-dialog-but-not-during-inline-e/4308172#4308172). The answer shows how you can **dynamically** change `editable` or any other properties of the column for the row *before* the editing started. In the way you can implement any scenario.