# how to use image in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i wanna hide image column when showing table, but it will show when i open edit dialog, and also, i wanna upload picture in edit dialog.so, what should i do? oh, yeap, i got a json string from my server contain a field which is url to display image.

my colModel setting(part of it):

```
{
    name:'operating_license',
    index:'operating_license', 
    width:60,
    hidden: false,
    editable: true,
    sortable: true,
    edittype: "image"
}
```

any help will be appreciate

Comment: Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25918007/315935) for an example how to use `edittype: "image"`.

Comment: the demo doesn't help me to solve it...i want to hide image column in table and show in edit dialog....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the example from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25918007/315935). If you need to hide the column with the image in the grid, but to display it in the editing dialog you need to add

```
hidden: true, editrules: {edithidden: true}
```

properties to the column.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithImages2.htm) demonstrates the results. It displays

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answering and patient.it works when i follow your answer although it take me a while to comprehend it.....anyway, thank you very much.there is no word can express my appreciate......

Comment: now, i'm looking for some plugin(e.g. ajaxFileUpload) to allow me upload picture when in edit dialog.

Comment: @MadisonRong: You are welcome! I don't use `ajaxFileUpload` myself.

Comment: so, do you have some plugin to recommend to me?

Comment: @MadisonRong: I don't need upload functionality in any my project which I made for my customers. So I think that you have more experience as me in the subject.