# jqGrid - Row Span in Add/Edit Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In one of my jqGrid Add/Edit Modal I want to arrange the fields in that way like on the picture below:

[image]

Thanks to Oleg that I have already know from [his post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850978/jqgrid-how-to-modify-form-editing-construction), how to arrange the fields in multiple column. But I want to do rowspan in the Add/Edit modal like on the picture below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created for you [small demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MulticolumnEdit2.htm) based on the demo from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25918007/315935). The demo have hidden column `flag` which provides the information to the URLs to the pictures. I defined the column like below

```
{ name: "flag", index: "flag", width: 55, hidden: true,
    edittype: "image", editrules: { edithidden: true },
    editoptions: { src: "", style: "margin-left: 20px" },
    formoptions: { label: "", rowpos: 1, colpos: 2}}
```

The Edit form use `beforeInitData` which set `src` attribute based on the value of `flag` and then one set all required properties of the Edit form inside of `beforeShowForm`. If one need to support Next/Prev buttons of the edit form then one should use `afterclickPgButtons` callback too. The final code is the following

```
$grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {add: false, del: false, search: false}, {
    recreateForm: true,
    width: 450,
    beforeInitData: function () {
        var $self = $(this),
            cm = $self.jqGrid("getColProp", "flag"),
            selRowId = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow"),
            lang = $self.jqGrid("getCell", selRowId, "flag");
        cm.editoptions.src = "http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/img/flag_" + lang + ".gif";
    },
    beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
        var $formRows = $form.find(".FormData");
        $formRows.eq(0).children("td.DataTD").eq(1).attr("rowspan", "3"); //.css("text-align", "center");
        $formRows.eq(1).children("td.DataTD").eq(1).hide();
        $formRows.eq(2).children("td.DataTD").eq(1).hide();
    },
    afterclickPgButtons: function () {
        var $self = $(this),
            selRowId = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow"),
            lang = $self.jqGrid("getCell", selRowId, "flag");
        $("#flag").attr("src", "http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/img/flag_" + lang + ".gif");
    }
});
```

It displays the results like

[image]