# How to disable editing for some cells in row editing of JQGrid?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

When I click on any row of my Grid, All editable columns become editable.

I want some of the columns to be editable on each row separately.

```
                 Column 1,   Column 2,     Column 3             
ROW Number 1 - editable,     non-editable, non-editable  
ROW Number 2 - non-editable, editable,     non-editable    
ROW Number 3 - editable,     non-editable, non-editable
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use [inline editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#editing) and want to decide *dynamically* which cells of the row will be editable for example based on the contain of the cells you can do this in the way which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307147/jqgrid-how-to-make-a-column-editable-in-the-add-dialog-but-not-during-inline-e/4308172#4308172). You can do this with another method also:

```
$(this).jqGrid('setColProp', 'YouColumnName', {editable:false});
```

So you should just set `editable` to `false` or `true` *before* calling of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) method. In the way you can implement any logic which you want.

**UPDATE:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) allows to define `editable` as callback function. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function). It allows to make the column editable in some rows and holding non-editable for other rows.

Comment: Ok, So that I can check the value of a cell in a row. And then make it editable : false. So it becomes non editable for the selected row right..?

Comment: @stacktrace: `editRow` method tests which columns are editable **at the moment**. It create `<input>` or `<select>` controls to the cell editing only for the editable columns. So if you set column property of some column temporary to `editable:false` no control for editing will be created and the corresponding cell will be non-editable like you as want. Directly after the call of the `editRow` method you can change the setting back to any value which you want. In the way you would full solve the problem which you have.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Will you please help me on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752611/how-to-avoid-scroll-to-top-when-i-click-on-any-non-editable-cell-in-jqgrid-subgr  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, just expanding on what [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg) already mentioned in his answer:

```
//get colModel properties
var cm = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getColProp','myColumn');

//some condition to enable or disable editing
cm.editable = false;

//always call editRow after changing editable property
jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('editRow', rowId, {});

//set default editable option
cm.editable = true;
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Why you don't call `jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('editRow', rowId, {});` at the end, after you set `cm.editable = true`?

Comment: Because that will set the cell to editable again. Here what you are trying to do is make a particular cell conditionally non-editable but rest of the columns stay editable. `cm.editable = true;` is to set col model back to editable whenever `editRow` is called again.