# How to avoid scroll to top, when i click on any Non-Editable Cell in JQGrid subgrid...?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using Cell Editing for a sub-grid in JQGrid.

When I set height of sub-grid to auto, By clicking on non editable cell, Grid scroll back to top.

And when i set height to be specific like 180 or something, That way, it does not scrolls to top. Selected cell remains in same position.

If i need to make height auto, How should i avoid scrolling back to top?

```
$("#listsg11").jqGrid({
url:'Any URL',
datatype: "json",
height: 190,
colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
    {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90},
    {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
    {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right"},
    {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right"},      
    {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right"},       
    {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
],
sortname: 'id',
viewrecords: true,
sortorder: "desc",
multiselect: false,
subGrid: true,
caption: "Grid as Subgrid",
subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
    var subgrid_table_id, pager_id;
    subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";

    $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");
    jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
        url:'Any URL with parameters',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['No','Item','Qty','Unit','Line Total'],
        colModel: [
            {name:"num",index:"num",width:80,key:true},
            {name:"item",index:"item",width:130,editable:true},
            {name:"qty",index:"qty",width:70,align:"right",editable:true},
            {name:"unit",index:"unit",width:70,align:"right",editable:false},
            {name:"total",index:"total",width:70,align:"right",sortable:false}
        ],
        cellEdit: true,
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
            height: 'auto'
    });

} });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use subgrids or [subgrids as grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid)? Could you post demo which can be used to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Hi Oleg, I've added following code.. Please check if you are having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using subgrids as grid, Same like given example in your link,
And following is an example code in which I've made changes to re-produce the problem.
I do not use pager div in any of my grids. And I've set height of Subgrid as 'auto'

When you click on any non editable CELL in last row of subgrid. Sub-grid should navigate back to top, But not my selected cell

Note: Subgrid data should be more than 30 rows approx.

Thanks

Comment: Please place the code always **in the text of your question** (you can modify the text any time by clicking "edit" link under the question). To allow other be able to reproduce your problem you should post test JSON data returned from the server. It will be enough to post the server response for filling the main grid and another JSON response for one subgrid. The data can be saved in the files and one will be able reproduce your problem. You can catch server response with respect of [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).