# How to disable the cell if the date is empty or null or undefined?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm new to jqgrid and jquery, can someone please help me in disabling the cell when the date is null or empty or undefined?
Actually the json for some (rows,col) date data is there and for some it is not there.
I want to disable the cell in the row for which Date data is not available.

grid cell editing POC

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jqGrid/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jqGrid/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_5.0.1/css/ui.jqgrid.css">

<script type="text/ecmascript" src="/jqGrid/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_5.0.1/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jqGrid/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jqGrid/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_5.0.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jqGrid/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_5.0.1/src/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {


            "use strict";
            var grid = $("#tree");

            var initDateWithButton = function (elem) {

                var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                   for (var i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
                 var id=ids[i];
           if (grid.jqGrid('getCell',id,'assignedDate') == null) {
                    grid.jqGrid('setCell',id,'assignedDate','','not-editable-cell');
                 }
           if (grid.jqGrid('getCell',id,'assignedDate') == "") {
                    grid.jqGrid('setCell',id,'assignedDate','','not-editable-cell');
                 }
           if (grid.jqGrid('getCell',id,'assignedDate') == undefined) {
                    grid.jqGrid('setCell',id,'assignedDate','','not-editable-cell');
                 }
             }


                        if (/^\d+%$/.test(elem.style.width)) {
                        // remove % from the searching toolbar
                        elem.style.width = '';
                    }
                    // to be able to use 'showOn' option of datepicker in advance searching dialog
                    // or in the editing we have to use setTimeout
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(elem).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                            showOn: 'button',
                            changeYear: true,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            showWeek: false,
                            showButtonPanel: true,
                            buttonImage: 'http://rcban0015:10039/GridPOC/pages/calenderIcon.gif',
                            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                                inst.input.focus();
                            }
                        });
                        $(elem).next('button.ui-datepicker-trigger').button({
                            text: false,
                            position: "relative",
                            top: "4px"
                        });
                    }, 100);

                },
                dateTemplate = {align: 'center', sorttype: 'date', editable: true,
                    formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-M-Y' }, datefmt: 'd-M-Y',
                    editoptions: { dataInit: initDateWithButton, size: 11 },
                    searchoptions: {
                        sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'],
                        dataInit: initDateWithButton,
                        size: 11,          // for the advanced searching dialog
                        attr: {size: 11}   // for the searching toolbar
                    }},
                lastSel;

            jQuery('#tree').jqGrid({
            url: '<%= webAppAccess.getBackchannelActionURL("actionListjqGridPagination",false) %>', 

               "colModel":[
     {
      "name":"course_id",
      "index":"course_id",
      "sorttype":"int",
      "key":true,
      "hidden":true,
      "width":50
     },{
      "name":"courseName",
      "index":"courseName",
      "sorttype":"string",
      "label":"courseName",
      "width":200
     },{
      "name":"facility",
      "index":"facility",

      "label":"facility",
      "width":200,
      "align":"left"
     },{
      "name":"assignedDate",
      "index":"assignedDate",
      "label":"assignedDate",
      "width":110,
      "template": dateTemplate
     },{
      "name":"dueDate",
      "index":"dueDate",
      "label":"dueDate",
      "width":110,
      "template": dateTemplate
     },
     {
      "name":"AssignmentStatus",
      "index":"AssignmentStatus",

      "label":"AssignmentStatus",
      "width":50
     },{
      "name":"Action",
      "index":"Action",

      "label":"Action",
      "width":50
     },
     {
      "name":"lft",
      "hidden":true
     },{
      "name":"rgt",
      "hidden":true
     },{
      "name":"level",
      "hidden":true
     },{
      "name":"uiicon",
      "hidden":true
     }
    ],

    "jsonReader": { "repeatitems": false, "root": "employees.rows" },
"toolbar": [true, "top"],
    "width":"1200",
    "hoverrows":false,
    "viewrecords":false,
    "gridview":true,
    "height":"auto",
    "sortname":"lft",
    "loadonce":true,
    "rowNum": 2,
    "rowList":[2,10,15],

    "scrollrows":true,
    // enable tree grid
    "treeGrid":true,
    // which column is expandable
    "ExpandColumn":"courseName",
    // datatype
    "treedatatype":"json",
    // the model used
    "treeGridModel":"nested",
    // configuration of the data comming from server
    "treeReader":{
      "left_field":"lft",
     "right_field":"rgt",
     "level_field":"level",
     "leaf_field":"isLeaf",
     "expanded_field":"expanded",
     "loaded":"loaded",
     // set the ui icon field froom data
     "icon_field":"uiicon"
    },
    "sortorder":"asc",
    "datatype":"json",
    "pager":"#pager",
    "cellEdit": true, // TRUE = turns on celledit for the grid.
    "cellsubmit" : 'clientArray',
    "editurl": 'clientArray'
   }); 

     $('#t_' +"tree")
                .append($("<div><label for=\"globalSearchText\">Global search in grid for:&nbsp;</label><input id=\"globalSearchText\" type=\"text\"></input>&nbsp;<button id=\"globalSearch\" type=\"button\">Search</button></div>"));
        $("#globalSearchText").keypress(function (e) {
                var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
                if (key === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) { // 13
                    $("#globalSearch").click();
                }
            });
            $("#globalSearch").button({
                icons: { primary: "ui-icon-search" },
                text: false
            }).click(function () {
                var postData = jQuery('#tree').jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData"),
                    colModel = jQuery('#tree').jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
                    rules = [],
                    searchText = $("#globalSearchText").val(),
                    l = colModel.length,
                    i,
                    cm;
                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    cm = colModel[i];
                    if (cm.search !== false && (cm.stype === undefined || cm.stype === "text")) {
                        rules.push({
                            field: cm.name,
                            op: "cn",
                            data: searchText
                        });
                    }
                }
                postData.filters = JSON.stringify({
                    groupOp: "OR",
                    rules: rules
                });
                jQuery('#tree').jqGrid("setGridParam", { search: true });
                jQuery('#tree').trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: 1, current: true}]);
                return false;
            });
  });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tree"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are exist alternative fork of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop since more as one year. It has the functionality, where one can define `editable` property of `colModel` as *function*, which can return `true` or `false` based on the cell or the row content. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are exist alternative fork of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop since more as one year. It has the functionality, where one can define `editable` property of `colModel` as *function*, which can return `true` or `false` based on the cell or the row content. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this [How to disable editing for soe cells in row editing of JQGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723621/how-to-disable-editing-for-some-cells-in-row-editing-of-jqgrid)
helps, it seen it is a similar thing, You just need to add into your logic.