# jqGrid - setColProp()

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to add row id to the `setColProp()` of jqGrid?

When I dynamically set `"editable":false` for a column, it sets `"editable":false` for ALL columns in the grid and not for a particular column of a particular row.

Comment: Which editing mode you use? (inline editing, cell editing or form editing?)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column property (for any column) before you call `editRow` and reset it back directly after the call `editRow`. In the way you can implement full dynamical `editable` option. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307147/jqgrid-how-to-make-a-column-editable-in-the-add-dialog-but-not-during-inline/4308172#4308172) for the code example.

Comment: It works if `editable` is not set in JSON response. But I have `editable` set in JSON and I'm checking for this value on `loadComplete`. Since I have the value coming in from JSON, it doesn't work if I change the order of row editing.

Answer (score 0):

You can using properties of column

```
{ name: 'COMPANY_ID', index: 'COMPANY_ID', align: 'left', editable: true }
```

After that you can set for col:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('setColProp', 'COMPANY_ID', { editable: false });
```