# Condtional editable depend on the value in colModel jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I am trying to put `editable` value either `true` or `false` depend on the value of the cell in `colModel`. Is there is any way to do that?

```js
{name:'keywords',index:'keywords', width:150, editable:true,edittype:'select',
editrules:{required: true},
editoptions:{value:{'one':'one','two':'two','three':'three','four':'four'},size:5} },
```

In this I want to set `editable:false` if the `cellvalue` exist else `editable:true` and `editoptions:{value:{'one':'one','two':'two',...}` for a particular cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way to implement the requirement would be to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). It's the fork (based on jqGrid 4.7) which I develop currently. Because of such requirements I implemented the feature described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function). It allows to define `editable` property *as function*. So you need just to define the callback from which you returns `true` or `false` base on any your custom criteria. The callback `editable` get many information about the context of execution as properties of the only parameter. The `rowid`, `iRow`, `iCol` and `name` properties allows you to use `getLocalRow` or `getCell` to get contain of any column of the row. So you can enable editing selectively in very simple way.

If you can't upgrade to free jqGrid then you can use old tricks which are specific for the editing mode which you use. I can forward you to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405961/315935) which can be used in case of form editing and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4308172/315935) which can be used in case of form editing if you call `editRow` directly. In case of usage `inlineNav` or `formatter: "actions"` there are alternative solutions which you can find also in my old answers.