# JqGrid - Show column, depending on mode (show in Edit-mode/hide in Add-mode)

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to implement a custom column which should be shown in edit-mode (as readonly), but not in Add-mode. Is there a possibility to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable/disable any row of the Add/Edit dialog inside of the [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) method. Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405029/jqgrid-disable-form-fields-when-editing/3405961#3405961) for an example.