# Jqgrid addform and editform option hack?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php, jqgrid-formatter

Is there anyway to set a column lke that:

```
Show in editform => True

Show in addform => False
```

Do you have any suggestions to do this?

I know "editable" option but doesn't give me what i need...

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405029/jqgrid-disable-form-fields-when-editing/3405961#3405961). I find the problem which you has very common. [The discussion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/discussion/form-editing-difference-between-add-and-edit/) about the subject could be interesting for you.