# jqgrid: Field required by add-form but not required by edit-form?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

an user has a password and it is required by add a user, but on edit-action a password is not required, but can be changed.

Is it possible to do this with jqgrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the value of `required` property of the [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editrules) inside of `beforeShowForm` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405961/315935)). You can use [setColProp](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) for example to do this. For example to set `required: true` in the 'password' you can call

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('setColProp', 'password', {editrules: {required: true}});
```

inside of `beforeShowForm`.