# How to edit the value of grouping field in JQGRID

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid which is grouped by some field. When I select a row, and press the edit icon, the edit form dos not show the grouping field.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid just set `hidden: true` property if you use `false` for some items of `groupColumnShow` array of `groupingView` option. Add and Edit forms contains the fields for such columns, but the corresponding `<tr>` elements of the data table in the form are hidden. You can show the rows in the same way like it described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405961/315935). If required you can automate the process by analyzing of `groupingView` dynamically inside of `beforeShowForm`.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditHiddenGroupingFileds.htm) uses the following code

```js
beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
    var groupingView = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "groupingView"), i,
        l = (groupingView !== null || $.isArray(groupingView.groupField)) ? groupingView.groupField.length : 0;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if ($.isArray(groupingView.groupColumnShow) && groupingView.groupColumnShow[i] === false) {
            $form.find("#tr_" + $.jgrid.jqID(groupingView.groupField[i])).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and it displays

[image]

in spite of usage the settings

```js
grouping: true,
groupingView: {
    groupField: ["name"],
    groupColumnShow: [false]
}
```