# jqGrid hide column on view depends another column value

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, dependencies

I want to show column `session` based on the corresponding row's cell value of `type`. Already `session` column is hidden.

To hide `session` column i used this below piece of code,

```
{ name: 'session', index: 'session', hidden:true, editrules:{edithidden:true} },
```

So, I just want to show this column value only in `view`. If `type` cell value is equal to `Full`, I want to hide `session` in `view`. Otherwise, I want to show that `session` column value in `view`.

I tried using this below code,

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
    var celValue = $('#statGrid').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'type');
    if (celValue === 'Full') $('#statGrid').jqGrid('getColProp', 'session').editrules.edithidden = false;
    if (celValue === 'Half') $('#statGrid').jqGrid('getColProp', 'session').editrules.edithidden = true;
}
```

Once, first `if` condition get success `edithidden` property changed to `false`. So, It hides `session` in View form. But I could not change that property to `true` when my second `if` condition get success.

Why this happened? Is this right way to do this task? or Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `beforeShowForm` and `afterclickPgButtons` callbacks of View options. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ShowColumnInView.htm) demonstrate it. The demo the the following code:

```
var showIdRow = function ($form) {
        var $this = $(this),
            rowid = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow"),
            isClosed = $this.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "closed");
        if (isClosed === "Yes") {
            $("#trv_id").show(); // "trv_" is the prefix, "id" is the column name
        }
    };

$("#list").jqGrid({
    ....
    colModel: [
        { name: "id", width: 65, hidden: true,  editrules: {edithidden: false} },
        ...
    ]
    ...
}).jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {view: true}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {
    recreateForm: true,
    afterclickPgButtons: showIdRow,
    beforeShowForm: showIdRow
});
```

The demo shows `"id"` column on View form only and only in case if chechbox in "Close" column is checked.

Comment: Thanks... Its working fine... We should `recreateForm` for each view?

Comment: @CJRamki: You are welcome! I strictly recommend to use `recreateForm: true` for Add, Edit and View and `recreateFilter: true` for searching.