# How to hide edit form of jqgrid pager

Tags: jqgrid

I am newbie to jqgrid. and for one requirement, I need to hide edit form that poped up when we click edit button of navbar(pager). How can I hide it based on condition.

on click of Edit button, I am checking how many rows are selected by user. if it is more than one, I need to hide edit form and need to show alert message that, they can only edit one record.

I did following but did not work.

```
beforeShowForm: function(form){
form.hide();
$("#editmodlist").css("display", "none"); // where I hardedcoded div that surounds edit form
}
```

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405029/jqgrid-disable-form-fields-when-editing) the answer you are looking for?

Comment: which answer @DieterDeRidder

Comment: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3405961/3532897), I hope this answer can help you.

Comment: Thanks @DieterDeRidder. but that did not help somehow. finally I found this way. may help someone.  beforeInitData: function(form){
                            var selRowIds = jQuery('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
                                 if(selRowIds.length>1){
                                  alert("Error");
                                  return false;
                             }else{
                              return true;
                             }
                            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just adding my solution here for better formatting of code.

```
beforeInitData: function(form){ 
var selRowIds = jQuery('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');   
if(selRowIds.length>1)
{
 alert("Error"); 
return false; 
}
else
{ 
return true; 
}
}
```